# Why does memory leak in one case and not in another

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am creating a `c++` object with two slightly different ways, in the following code when `CASE` is `0` there is a memory leak, but no memory leak in the `else` case.

```
#include <string>
#define CASE 1

class A {
private:
  std::string *s;
public:
  A(std::string *p_s) { s = p_s; }
};

int main() {
#if CASE==0
  auto a = A(new std::string("Hello"));
#else
  auto s = std::string("Hello");
  auto a = A(&s);
#endif
}
```

when I set `CASE 0` the `valgrind` says that there is a memory leak

```
valgrind ./a.out 
==24351== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==24351== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==24351== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==24351== Command: ./a.out
==24351== 
==24351== 
==24351== HEAP SUMMARY:
==24351==     in use at exit: 32 bytes in 1 blocks
==24351==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 72,736 bytes allocated
==24351== 
==24351== LEAK SUMMARY:
==24351==    definitely lost: 32 bytes in 1 blocks
==24351==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24351==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24351==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24351==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24351== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==24351== 
==24351== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==24351== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

in the else case (i.e. `define CASE 1`)  it works as expected and valgrind doesn't report any memory leak.

I am not able to understand in either case I am passing a pointer and I am not explicitly freeing the memory then why do they behave differently?

Comment: In the first case, you allocate some memory with `new`, so you must release it with `delete`. In the second case, you just take a pointer to an object on the stack - no need to `delete` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CASE==0**

```
auto a = A(new std::string("Hello"));
```

This means you are `new`-ing an object in heap -> you have to **explicitly** `delete` it - that you didn't in the snippet -> memory leaks.

**else**

```
auto s = std::string("Hello");
auto a = A(&s);
```

- `auto s = std::string("Hello");`: This means you are creating an object in stack and,
- `auto a = A(&s);`: take its address (in stack, of course).
- The created object will be auto-deleted once the variable goes out of scope

-> no memory leak.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this behavior is that your class `A` is not designed to take ownership of `std::string*` passed into it: its `std::string *s` member assumes that the object the pointer to which is passed into the constructor would be destroyed externally.

This leads to a memory leak when the object is not destroyed: `delete` is never called on `new string` passed into the constructor in the first case, causing a memory leak.

In the second case the pointer points to a string in automatic storage. It gets destroyed when `main` ends, preventing the memory leak.

Answer (score 4):

You don't get a memory leak because you have a pointer.

You get a memory leak because you `new`'d something and did not `delete` it.

Obtaining a pointer to an automatic storage variable does not stop the variable from being cleaned up automatically.

In fact, attempting to `delete &a` in that case would be wrong/broken/evil/illegal/heresy.

Answer (score 1):

This is no different from:

```
// first case, leak
int *j = new int (5);
//
// second case, no leak
int q = 5;
int *j = &q;
```

In the first case, we've allocated memory with `new` and it's our responsibility to `delete` it when we're done. In the second case, we create `q` on the stack and it's destroyed when it goes out of scope.